# reading/writing from ostringstream changes original data

Tags: c++, ostringstream

Inside a test, I write a given value to an `ostringstream`. After that, I try to evaluate if the correct value was written. However, it seems that the original value I wrote into the stream is changed later on while reading from it.

I reduced my problem to the following code:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    uint16_t data{ 123 };
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(uint16_t));

    uint16_t data_returned;
    std::string data_str(os.str());
  
    std::copy(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), &data_returned);

    assert(data == 123); // <- not true
    assert(data_returned == 123);
}
```

Here `data` seems to be changed (to 0) by `std::copy()`.

I also put the code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/bcb4PE

Even more strange, if I change `uint16_t data{ 123 };` to `const uint16_t data{ 123 };`, everything is fine.

Seems like I am missing some insights on the mechanics of `std::copy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::copy()` does not do what you think it does in this situation.  It is just a wrapper for a logical loop that copies *individual* elements from one container to another.  You are essentially telling it to copy 2 individual `chars` from `data_str` into a `uint16_t[2]` array, except that you don't actually have such as array, so you have *undefined behavior* and are corrupting stack memory.

This statement:

```cpp
std::copy(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), &data_returned);
```

Is basically doing this:

```cpp
std::string::iterator iter = data_str.begin(), end = data_str.end();
uint16_t *dest = &data_returned;
while (iter != end) {
    *dest++ = *iter++;
}
```

Which is basically just the equivalent of doing this, in your example:

```cpp
uint16_t *dest = &data_returned;
dest[0] = static_cast<uint16_t>(data_str[0]);
dest[1] = static_cast<uint16_t>(data_str[1]);
```

It is assigning the 1st *byte* to the whole `uint16_t` (which is why you see the value change), and then it is assigning the 2nd *byte* to the *next* whole `uint16_t` (corrupting the stack).

For what you are attempting, use `std::memcpy()` instead, eg:

```
std::memcpy(&data_returned, data_str.c_str(), sizeof(data_returned));
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use `std::copy()`, you need to make sure it knows to copy *individual bytes* into the destination, not whole `uint16_t`s, eg:

```cpp
std::copy(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data_returned));
```

Since both input and output are trivial types, that should get optimized down to an appropriate `std::memcpy()`-equivalent copy.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `std::copy()` this way, you need to cast `&data_returned` to a `char*`, or else `std::copy()` will treat it as an `uint16_t*` and populate two `uint16_t`s instead of the two `char`s you aimed for. This makes your program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and that's why you see a changed value in `data`. The program could just as well have crashed or done something completely different.

```cpp
std::copy(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data_returned));
```

Here's your program compiled with two extra options (`-ggdb -fsanitize=address`) to make it easier to catch problems like this in the future: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KjMqE7)